# Name of the mathematical term $\frac{a-b}{a+b}$

Tags: definition

I calculated a kind of proportion between $a$ and $b$, not $\frac{a}{b}$ but

$$\frac{a-b}{a+b}$$

Do this mathematical term has a name? If so, it would help me to explain my calculations...

Comment: Proportion between $a-b$ and $a+b$?

Comment: Can you give some examples of similar “named” expressions?

Comment: Maybe [componendo and dividendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Matthew: I suspect things like "the arithmetic mean" and "geometric mean" would be good examples of named expressions (or, indeed, "the square root"!)

Comment: It's also not uncommon to call $a+b$ and $a-b$ *conjugates*, so that could reasonably be called a ratio of conjugates (although I've never *seen* such a statement).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I would have like a name which allows to understand that it is a kind of proportion...

Comment: @Ishu (otherwise, you found a correct name, thanks !)

Answer (score 1):

$${{a-b} \over {a+b}}$$ can be split into ${a \over {a+b}}$ and $-{b \over {a+b}}$. These two terms are the Percentage Fractions. The term with $a$ in the numerator could also be considered as a probability.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could safely call this "the relative difference of $a$ and $b$," at least if *both are positive*.

I say "*relative* difference" because it's clearly related to the difference, but it's scaled by the size of the numbers: if you doubled both $a$ and $b$, you'd get the same result. (Put differently, if $a$ and $b$ are measurements, it doesn't matter whether you use a yardstick or a meter-stick to take them, because the relative difference will be the same.)

By the way, this "relative difference," if both are positive, will always be between $-1$ and $1$.

Despite this, I'm not certain that giving this thing a name is a particularly good idea, unless you need to write about it in a long paper where it's going to be used multiple times, and need to save space.

Comment: Your answer brings me to the [Wikipedia definition of *relative difference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference) and then [here](http://ecp.acponline.org/janfeb00/primer.htm). Their two definitions does not seem consistent... If wikipedia is right, the relative difference would be in [0, 1] because of the absolute value of the numerator.
Anyway, you're right I shouldn't name this number as it is unclear.

Comment: Ah...I had no idea that "relative difference" had already been defined! Glad to have been of some service.